# Krull Topology on a Galois Group Definition

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, profinite-groups

I want to start study infinite galois theory and I have a problem with a basic definition:

The definition of Krull topology.
So $L/K$ is a Galoisextension, $F$ is a subfield $K\subseteq F\subseteq L$ and
$\mathcal{N}:=\{Gal(L/F)\subseteq Gal(L/K)\text{ }|\text{ }[F:K]<\infty, F/K \text{  galois}\}$.

We define an open neighborhood basis of $\sigma$ as a set of $\sigma\mathcal{N}$.
Now I want to verify that this defines a topology.
We have $U\subseteq Gal(L/K)$ is open if and only if there exists for every $\sigma\in Gal(L/K)$
an Element $S$ in the neighborhood basis such that $S\subseteq U$.

So I don't understand why the empty set is open can somebody explain it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't need to be true for every $\sigma$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$, it needs to be true for every $\sigma$ in $U$. If $U$ is the empty set, this is true vacuously - every $\sigma$ in $U$ admits some $S$ such that blah blah blah since there are no elements in $U$ to begin with.